# Intersection of Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, soft-question

What mathematical areas lie at the intersection of algebraic geometry and algebraic topology? I'm aware of certain ones such as derived algebraic geometry and motivic homotopy theory, which all involve a fair amount of higher category theory. Are there any areas at the intersection that focus more on the algebraic geometry/algebraic topology themselves rather than more on the category theory? Do certain aspects of derived geometry satisfy this criteria, such as the recent work on derived symplectic geometry [PTVV]? For instance, reading some books such as Lurie's HTT and Higher Algebra seems more focused on category theory rather than homotopy theory itself.

Comment: this is a very naive response, but one specific object to look at is the étale fundamental group of a scheme and associated/similar things, since it is the algebro-geometric analogue of the usual $\pi_1$.

Comment: This is probably not a very good response. But what I think of is cohomology. Sometimes computing cohomology in algebraic geometry and algebraic topology are equivalent, even though they are defined quite differently. Perhaps, a problem of intersection between these two subjects, is to study some cohomology bridge among these two theories?

Comment: One of the important directions is towards Shafarevich's conjecture. Have a look at Kollar's book.

Comment: "It was my lot to plant the harpoon of algebraic topology into the belly of the whale of algebraic geometry." -- Lefschetz. (Cf. Noether-Lefschetz theory.)

Comment: Motivic homotopy theory combines scheme theory with homotopy theory in order to define motives.

Comment: To a great extent, general homotopy theory and higher category theory are the same subject.

Comment: HTT and HA are, to a certain extent, about higher category theory, but they're just higher categorical foundations for what follows. Lurie's DAG seems to fit the bill, it simply uses HA and HTT as tools, and builds on them - it happens that (derived) algebraic geometry and algebraic topology (rather, homotopy theory) rely a lot on categorical techniques

Comment: Recently, motivic homotopy theory has been doing some real intersection theory. (pun intended.)  In particular, I have Kass-Wickelgren's "An Arithmetic Count of the Lines on a Smooth Cubic Surface" in mind.  Ultimately, I think the focus on higher category theory in these subjects has largely been a focus on laying some hardcore foundations in pursuit of geometry and topology.